# iOS: method and data within table view being called too early

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimageview

I am trying to go through a group of images on the screen, each with a delay in between.

```
func showImageAtIndex(index: Int) {

    // all UI updates happen on the main queue
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        if (index) >  self.images.count-1 { self.otherView.removeFromSuperview()
            self.imageView?.removeFromSuperview()
            return
        }


        self.imageView?.image = self.images[index]


        let delayTime = 0.13
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delayTime * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in

            self.showImageAtIndex(index + 1)
        }
    }
```

in my table view, when a button is clicked, the method showImageAtIndex is called

```
func onAdd(sender: AnyObject) {
self.temp=self.lotteryMachine.setPossibleCombinations(currentStandings)
    //i took out the image view stuff bc its not necessary
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem!.enabled = false
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem!.enabled = false
    self.showImageAtIndex(0)
    tableView.reloadData()
   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem!.enabled = true
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem!.enabled = true
}
```

What I want to know is why the data in the table is reloaded first, and then the images are loaded rather than the other way around. What i would like to happen is for the images to load and then the data is updated after that delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `showImageAtIndex` function uses `dispatch_async`, which means everything within the closure happens asynchronously.

The call to `showImageAtIndex(0)` returns immediately, and the call to `tableView.reloadData()` occurs before the delayed code within the `dispatch_after` closure is executed.

Try moving the `tableView.reloadData()` after the call to `showImageAtIndex(index + 1)` within the `dispatch_after` closure.

Comment: I get why its reloading the data early, but when I move it within the dispatch_after segment, it still reloads it too early. I think because it is a recursive function, it will reload the data after the first call (the first image shown) , but I wanted it to load after all the array of images has been shown. Since i know the length of the array should i just set up a count and increment it every time and if it is equal to the length-1, just reload the data?

Comment: That should work, if you are doing the check and reloading the data within the dispatch_after.

Comment: i ended up putting it within the first if statement in the dispatch async and it works fine